# How powerful is the Rinne Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

It's clear now that ***Rinnegan*** boasts the most powerful **dojutsu** out of the 3 dojutsu (not including *Tenseigan* here).

There are few occurrence where we got to saw ***Rinne Sharingan*** in action. So, where does it put the power of *Rinne-Sharingan*?

The current power level is laid out as such:

*Sharingan 1st < Sharingan 2nd < Sharingan 3rd < Byakugan < Mangekyo Sharingan < Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan < One eye Rinnegan < Both eyes Rinnegan*

Where does the ***Rinne Sharingan*** lie?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Sasuke doesn't have a Rinne-Sharingan. He has a Rinnegan. And about the  power level comparison, can you provide the source from where you got it?

Comment: @EroSɘnnin please see my edits regarding Sasuke Rinne-Sharingan. Also regarding the power level, i would say the Naruto manga is the source since there is no mention of these power level in the databook. I think the power level i mentioned above is pretty straight forward.  I wonder if there is any canon source that doesn't agree with it.

Comment: The details are not accurate. Please check the list of [Rinne-Sharingan users](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinne_Sharingan). You wont find Sasuke there because [he is a Rinnegan user.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) As for the comparison of dojutsu, it is opinion based as there is no official source to back that comparison

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Yes, you are right. Rinnegan with tomoe and Sharingan powers = still just a Rinnegan. Rinne-Sharinagn is a Kekei Mora and Rinnegan is a Kekei Genkai and Sasuke has a Kekei Genkai. Now it begs another question. What is the difference between Kaguya's Rinne-sharingan and Sasuke's Rinnegan with Tomoe?

Comment: The Sage of Six Paths said the Rinne Sharingan was the original Dojutsu that both the Sharingan and Rinnegan descended from. From this, we can assume it has both their powers. Considering Madara had to awaken it before casting Infinite Tsukyomi, I'd say it's more powerful than even Rinnegan in both eyes.

Comment: I'm really not sure about how you have rated the power level. For example, I really don't see byakugan less powerful than sharingan 1st tomoe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the Infinite Tsukuyomi, it should be ahead of everything except the Rinnegan. It should be above them as well but Kaguya didn't show enough of it to be a 100% sure.

Note: I wouldn't necessarily put the Sharingan above the Byakugan, especially the incomplete versions.

Comment: Have to +1 the comment about sharingan and byakugan as the byakugans powers are vastly different from the sharingan 1st powers. They seem pretty even at that level at least.